# Send an array through jquery with ajax to start zip stream from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, download, php-ziparchive

I think I have this narrowed down to being a problem with trying to download a file through the AJAX request. I need to push the array to the php script, but the zip download that the script pushes back has to be redirected to a new window. Not sure how to fit that into my jquery.

I'm not sure if it counts as a duplicate to other questions involving downloading from php, because the ones I looked at didn't pass data through the ajax call.

---

I am passing an array from jquery to php through AJAX and getting a streaming zip download of files from my database.  The script works when I navigate to it directly and downloads the zip file of files as expected. It does not however work when I try to trigger it through my jquery. I believe this has to do with the download needing to be redirected to a new window?

**Jquery:**

```
 if (confirm("Download data for the following samples:" + download_list.toString())) { alert("Download Beginning - Will take several minutes per sample selected - DON NOT NAVIGATE AWAY FROM PAGE.");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myURL +  "zip_download.php",
        data: {download_listArray:download_list},

        success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$sample_name_list = $_POST['download_listArray'];



foreach ($sample_name_list as $i => $sample_name){

   //do stuff
}
//stream zip

?>
```

Comment: the problem is that when you send a request via AJAX, the returned data (in this case the Zip file data) comes back to the Javascript which send the request (it becomes a parameter given to the "success" function) - it does not get displayed in the browser or downloaded to disk. You _can_ download files via AJAX but it's fiddly and involves what are essentially workarounds, I wouldn't recommend it really, it's not what AJAX is intended for. Maybe just get the AJAX part to send back a unique URL which you can then redirect the browser to, which will trigger the actual download?

Comment: Hmm, so instead of streaming the zip file, I should save it to a location and then pass that download back as the success?

Comment: yeah, pass the URL of the saved file back in the AJAX success. Then you can use window.open or window.location in Javascript to get the browser to visit that URL in a non-AJAX way. (To stop lots of files building up over time, you might also want to have a cron job running in the background on your server which deletes older files from the folder where you are saving them. Consider also whether these files need any security protection, e.g. if only certain users should be able to open them.)